# The report cannot be displayed. (rsProcessingAborted)

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am using Dynamics CRM 2011 on premise.

Reports were working fine a few days ago. Today they don't.

I am getting this error: "`The report cannot be displayed. (rsProcessingAborted)`"

[image]

I just run a report with warning level tracing on and this was logged:

```
[2013-07-09 14:10:50.099] Process:CrmAsyncService |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:  102 |Category: Sandbox.LoadBalancer |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Warning |ReqId: 0792ea86-fee7-4f86-b38a-00b5cf68cf57 | SandboxHostManager.PingSingleClient  ilOffset = 0xB8
>ping: exception: SRV-CRM02: System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at net.tcp://srv-crm02/CrmSandboxHost that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
[2013-07-09 14:10:50.512] Process:CrmAsyncService |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:  102 |Category: Sandbox |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Warning |ReqId: 0792ea86-fee7-4f86-b38a-00b5cf68cf57 | SandboxClientBase`1.Stop  ilOffset = 0xD
>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException: The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Close()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxClientBase`1.Stop()
```

This is in the reporting service log: http://pastebin.com/qm8FLzrn

Comment: How is your server set up, is it one server or several? Take a look at the services, this log seems to indicate that the sandbox service isn't responding, but it seems unlikely that is involved in the reports. You could try to publish the reports again, the SSRS log seems to indicate that there are some problems with the reports.

Comment: The User Summary report works.

It looks like all the reports that we've made fail.

We have two CRM servers both with IIS and CRM installed that are supposed to be load sharing. They are called srv-crm01 and srv-crm01. The databases are on a separate server called srv-sql01. This is the reporting server.

The sandbox service is running on srv-crm02.

Comment: Start by taking a look at this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699823.aspx, Sandbox is using port 808 for communication so that might need opening. Second thing I would look into is SPNs. I've seen this happen before that the default reports are working but not custom reports. It might of course also be a problem with the report. Can you run the report from the SSRS directly?

Comment: Do you mean by going to http://srv-sql01/ReportServer in browser?

Comment: Yes, see if the report works in the server, if it doesn't work there, something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by removing ports from SPNs.

Thanks to Alen at Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

I will put on how I have solved it in my particular case.
I had the same error, with the following preconditions:
- Customized report that works in the test environment, but does not work in production.
- All other reports work.
- CRM 365 online.

In my case, I had a parameter that obtained the values of a query and the Value field of that parameter was not pointing properly to the value field returned by that query.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, I had to change the pointing value field to "countValue" (previously it was "count" on the dropdown list).

Here are the fields of the DataSet:
[image]

What I can't understand is why it worked in other environments ...