# CRM 2011 Dashboard

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dashboard

I am using CRM-2011 for dashboard I created a report and show it in Dashboard. It is working fine but some time it gives error (like when refresh after some time).

when working fine
[image]

when error

[image]

note that report is always fine but problem in dashboard.
If anyone have an idea please share.

Comment: what error your are getting in trace?

Comment: Have a look at the answer, looks like possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549402/the-report-cannot-be-displayed-rsprocessingaborted